# Como se arredonda por excesso em PHP?

Tags: php, matemática

Qual a função do PHP para arredondar por excesso?

Exemplo:

`1.1` passar a `2`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a função [`ceil()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php).

```
echo ceil(1.1);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/9x7SMu). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bwiucvqh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Math/Ceil.php).

Comment: Meus votos acabaram, depois eu voto nas outras.

Comment: o que podemos fazer quando surgem tantas respostas iguais?

Comment: Eu simplesmente aceito a que é mais votada e pronto

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não tem muito o que fazer. Neste caso ninguém copiou de ninguém (que já não teria muito o que fazer a não ser comentar para a pessoa evitar isto).

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não acho necessário. A sua e até as outras em menor grau possuem características diferentes que podem ajudar no entendimento geral.

Comment: ok. Adicionei mais informações.

Comment: Estão dando +1 adoidado agora. Será que a intenção é gerar "votos em série removido" de propósito? kkkkkk

Comment: @WallaceMaxters isto não reverte.

Answer (score 4):

Em PHP para arrendondar por excesso usa-se a função `ceil`.

Exemplo

```
echo ceil(4.3);    // 5
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a função `ceil`.

```
ceil(1.1); // Imprime 2
```

Essa função geralmente é utilizada para saber o número de páginas que serão geradas numa paginação.

Exemplo:

```
$total = 100;
$limit = 12;
$pages = ceil($total / $limit); // Imprime 9
```

Ela serve para arredondar frações para cima.

Apenas pra você ter informação adiciona: A função contrária a essa é `floor`. Ela arredonda para baixo.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
echo ceil(1.1);  // 2
echo ceil(4.3);    // 5
echo ceil(9.999);  // 10
echo ceil(-3.14);  // -3
?>
```